# Fatal error:Call to a member function __setSoapHeaders() in sforceBaseclient.php

Tags: php, cakephp, salesforce

I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function __setSoapHeaders() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\fsc\app\Model\Datasource\soapclient\SforceBaseClient.php on line 188 .

I am using cakephp framework.when I try to add account data in salesforce account-list using create() method. this __setSoapHeaders() is in setHeader() function which gives this error.what is solution to this error?

In the sforceBaseclient.php,there is one function called setHeader() :

```
private function setHeaders($call=NULL) {
    **$this->sforce->__setSoapHeaders(null); [it gives above error.]**
      .
      .
    }
```

and I want to add Account details in the salesforce account as user get registered or do any transaction in our website. so i put following code in my Account model just for test , may be its creating any problem:

```
$mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
$fieldsToUpdate = array(
  'AccountNumber'  => 123456,
  'BillingCity'    => 'Testcity',
  'BillingCountry' => 'Testcountry',
  'BirthDate'      => '27-04-1992'
);

$sObject = new stdClass();
$sObject->fields = $fieldsToUpdate;
$sObject->type = 'Account';

try {
  $CreateResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array ($sObject),'Account');
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "<BR>Error Creating the Case! ";
  echo $e->faultstring;
  exit;
}

//To Make sure the case was created successfully.

if ($CreateResponse->success != 1) {
  echo "<BR>Error Creating the Account. ";
  print_r($CreateResponse->errors->message);
  exit;
}
```

what is solve to this error?

initially connect() is called which have code:

```
public function connect() {
        if (empty($this->config['username']) || empty($this->config['password']) || empty($this->config['wsdl'])) {
        $this->error = "Your username-password-wsdl must all be set";
        $this->showError();
        return false;
        }
        $wsdl = APP.'model/datasource/soapclient/'.$this->config['wsdl'];
                 $wsdl = str_replace('\\','/',$wsdl);
                $mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
        $mySforceConnection->createConnection($wsdl);
        $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection($wsdl);
                $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login($this->config['username'], $this->config['password']);
               $this->client = $mySforceConnection;
        return $mySforceConnection;
            }
```

here in this function u can see createConnection and Login is called...which has code

```
public function createConnection($wsdl, $proxy=null) {
            $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = 'Salesforce/PHPToolkit/1.0';
                $soapClientArray = null;
        if (phpversion() > '5.1.2') {
        $soapClientArray = array (
                'user_agent' => 'toolkit-php',            
                 'encoding' => 'utf-8',
                 'trace' => 1,
                'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP
            );
        } else {
        $soapClientArray = array (
                 'user_agent' => 'toolkit-php',            
               'encoding' => 'utf-8',
                'trace' => 1
            );
        }
        if ($proxy != null) {
        $proxySettings = array();
            $proxySettings['proxy_host'] = $proxy->host;
        $proxySettings['proxy_port'] = $proxy->port; // Use an integer, not a string
        $proxySettings['proxy_login'] = $proxy->login; 
                 $proxySettings['proxy_password'] = $proxy->password;
        $soapClientArray = array_merge($soapClientArray, $proxySettings);
        }
        $this->sforce = new SoapClient($wsdl, $soapClientArray);
        return $this->sforce;
            }
```

and then login()

```
public function login($username, $password) {
    $this->sforce->__setSoapHeaders(NULL);
    if ($this->callOptions != NULL) {
        $this->sforce->__setSoapHeaders(array($this->callOptions));
    }
    if ($this->loginScopeHeader != NULL) {
        $this->sforce->__setSoapHeaders(array($this->loginScopeHeader));
    }
    $result = $this->sforce->login(array (
             'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password
    ));
    $result = $result->result;
    $this->_setLoginHeader($result);
    return $result;
        }
```

this code works perfect...now as i mentioned above i am trying to add record using create methos in Account model..so first create method called which is in class called SforceEnterpriseClient.php

```
 public function create($sObjects, $type) {
               foreach ($sObjects as &$sobject) {
                 $sobject = new SoapVar($sobject, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, $type, $this->namespace);
                }
                 $arg = $sObjects;
                return parent::_create(new SoapParam($arg, "sObjects"));
               }
```

here u can see __create is called ehich is in sorceBaseClient class...

```
protected function _create($arg) {
        $this->setHeaders("create");
       return $this->sforce->create($arg)->result;
        }
```

here first setHeader function is called....

```
private function setHeaders($call=NULL) {
       **$this->sforce->__setSoapHeaders(null);** // as I told this line gives error at this point..if I comment it below __setSoapHeaders() gives error.and if I comment that create() function gives error....
    $header_array = array (
    $this->sessionHeader
    );
    $header = $this->callOptions;
    if ($header != NULL) {
    array_push($header_array, $header);
    }
        if ($call == "create" ||
    $call == "merge" ||
    $call == "update" ||
    $call == "upsert"
    ) {
        $header = $this->assignmentRuleHeader;
        if ($header != NULL) {
            array_push($header_array, $header);
        }
    }
    if ($call == "login") {
        $header = $this->loginScopeHeader;
        if ($header != NULL) {
            array_push($header_array, $header);
        }
    }
    if ($call == "create" ||
    $call == "resetPassword" ||
    $call == "update" ||
    $call == "upsert"
    ) {
        $header = $this->emailHeader;
        if ($header != NULL) {
            array_push($header_array, $header);
        }
    }
    if ($call == "create" ||
    $call == "merge" ||
    $call == "query" ||
    $call == "retrieve" ||
    $call == "update" ||
    $call == "upsert"
    ) {
        $header = $this->mruHeader;
        if ($header != NULL) {
            array_push($header_array, $header);
        }
    }
    if ($call == "delete") {
        $header = $this->userTerritoryDeleteHeader;
        if ($header != NULL) {
            array_push($header_array, $header);
        }
    }
    if ($call == "query" ||
    $call == "queryMore" ||
    $call == "retrieve") {
        $header = $this->queryHeader;
        if ($header != NULL) {
            array_push($header_array, $header);
        }
    }
    $this->sforce->__setSoapHeaders($header_array);
       }
```

and i cant understand I 'create' is passed from __create methos to setHeader function..and If i print $call(received parameter),it prints "Query"...so this is the code i have traced...

Answer (score 0):

What's unclear? PHP tell you that you call a function on a wrong object. That means exactly what it says: `__setSoapHeaders()` should be called on SoapClient object and in your script it is not. In other words `$this->sforce` is not SoapClient object. See/show your other code on why.

Comment: but this object is created in the same class in createconnection function : $this->sforce = new SoapClient($wsdl, $soapClientArray); still it gives error..

Comment: in other functions like login(), this __setSoapHeaders() is also used..and works perfectly..only in setHeaders() function it gives error...

Comment: Well obviously then the function `createconnection` is not being called before the `setHeaders`. The fact that `$this->sforce` is not what you expect it to be is enough data to start digging why and where is the problem. You don't post the code so how do you expect me to find the problem?)

Comment: ok i have posted code above..i have trace code but createConnection function called before setHeader still working perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and found the cause to be the fact that I had the path wrong to the wsdl xml - you might want to check this line:

$wsdl = APP.'model/datasource/soapclient/'.$this->config['wsdl'];

I now it's late but this might help someone else!